# Mak js file globally accessible in react-app without including as script

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import

```js
var theMovieDb = {};

theMovieDb.credits = {
  getDetails: function(options, success, error) {
    'use strict';

    theMovieDb.common.validateRequired(arguments, 3, options, ["id"]);

    theMovieDb.common.validateCallbacks(success, error);

    theMovieDb.common.client({
        url: "credit/" + options.id + theMovieDb.common.generateQuery(options)
      },
      success,
      error
    );
  }
};
```

The above code is from one of the node_modules files.
I tried both ways of including the file, with require and with import also!
But it wouldn't because it has no export. How can i access it without adding script tag. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is `module exports` ?

Comment: the node_module doesn't have a module exports ! @JonasWilms

Comment: Yeah why do you think that you can import things that you havent exported?